# C#, cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string[]'

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I have some C# code:

```
var oldLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
var newLines = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains(wordToDelete));
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);
```

The code works in a new windows application.  But when I paste that code into my existing app, I get these errors:

```
Error   2   Argument 2: cannot convert from
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for
'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])' has some invalid
arguments
```

Why would this error be thrown in a new project, but not in my old project?

Comment: What version of the framework does your existing app target?

Comment: 3.5, I'll change it to what you recommend?  4 client profile is on my new app where it works, I bet that fixes it?! :)

Comment: Makes me glad that I decided never to use those modern new-fangled "var" things. :-)

Comment: Seems like being facetious cost me an accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newLines` is an `IEnumerable<string>` not a `string[]`, but your .NET version (I assume 3.5) does not have the [overload which accepts an `IEnumerable<String>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), that was introduced in .NET 4.

So you just need to create a `string[]` for [`File.WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or use at least .NET 4:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains(wordToDelete)); returns a IEnumerable< string>

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines.ToArray());
```

will fix it,

This is probably caused by another framework version target.